# How create a function pointer to point a member function?

Tags: c++, pointers

Code:

```
struct A
{
    void* f(void *)
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    void * (*fp)(void *);
    fp = &A::f;
}
```

Compile:

```
|12|error: cannot convert 'void* (A::*)(void*)' to 'void* (*)(void*)' in assignment|
```

I have tried many ways, but all failed... How to do that?

Comment: Check out [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a regular member pointer, you'll need to declare the type it's a member of on the pointer type;

```
int main()
{
    void * (A::*fp)(void *);
    fp = &A::f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use function pointers use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

```
auto func = std::mem_fn(&A::f);
```

If you really want to use function pointers(you don't) you have to do this.

```
void * (A::*func)(void*);
func = &A::f;
```

IMO this is uglier, harder to read and less maintainable

---

You can also use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) like this.

```
A a;
std::function<void*(const A &, void*)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
```

but `mem_fn` is better suited for the job since you have a memfunction

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::function<void *( A&, void *)> fp = &A::f;
```