# Pointers to function members

Tags: c++

Given the following simple code:

```
namespace exercise {

class A {
public:

    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
    virtual void c() = 0;

};

class B : public A {

    void a() { std::cout << "a function @ B class"; }
    void b() { std::cout << "b function @ B class"; }
    void c() { std::cout << "c function @ B class"; }

};

class C : public A {

    void a() { std::cout << "a function @ C class"; }
    void b() { std::cout << "b function @ C class"; }
    void c() { std::cout << "c function @ C class"; }
};

using Pstd_mem = void(A::*)();

void foo(A* basePointer, Pstd_mem action) {

    basePointer->*action();

}
}

int main(void) {

using namespace exercise;

A* b = new B();
A* c = new C();

foo(b, &A::b);

}
```

I'm just trying to call the function B() through a pointer to member function using the function foo but the compiler gives me an error on the line:

```
basePointer->*action();
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266582/how-create-a-function-pointer-to-point-a-member-function/18266621#18266621) might help

Comment: _What_ error? Show us what you see.

Comment: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to) function type

Comment: What is the error message, and in what line?  Also, be sure of including all code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The error in GCC 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/YfoRec) is self-explanatory:

> error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘action (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* action) (...)’
>
> ```
> basePointer->*action();
> ```

So, simply do that:

```
(basePointer->*action)();
```